# Some operations not respecting custom attributes in Series subclass

Tags: python, pandas

According to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/internals.html
I should be able to sublcass a pandas Series

My [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is

```
from pandas import Series


class Xseries(Series):
    _metadata = ['attr']

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return Xseries

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.attr = kwargs.pop('attr', 0)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

s = Xseries([1, 2, 3], attr=3)
```

Notice that the `attr` attribute is:

```
s.attr

3
```

However, when I multiply by `2`

```
(s * 2).attr

0
```

Which is the default.  Therefore, the `attr` was not passed on.  You may ask, maybe that isn't the intended behavior?  I think it is according to the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/internals.html#define-original-properties

And if we use the `mul` method, it seems to work

```
s.mul(2).attr

3
```

And this doesn't (which is the same as `s * 2`)

```
s.__mul__(2).attr

0
```

---

I wanted to put this passed SO before I created an issue on github.  Is this a bug?

Is there a workaround?

I need to be able to do `s * 2` and have the `attr` attribute passed on to the result.

Comment: Sir its really hard to answer a question from you. I'm trying to come up with an answer  from morning,but that `_metadata` is not inheritable don't know why. Maybe when the data is passed to _init_ for manipulation the attr attribute is erased by Series constructor due to `super` maybe.

Comment: Sir surprisingly `s*=2` and `s.attr` has 3

Comment: Yes! there is something about `__mul__`, `__add__`,  or any of the operator methods that isn't propagating the `attr`

Comment: Sir I think we need to use `__finalize__` to copy attributes from one object to other. I tried that but couldnt complete because I dont know how to pass the unmanipuated object as the `other` parameter .  So you created an issue on github?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `inspect.getsourcelines`  to check the source code of these two functions `mul` and `__mul__`, you will find they actually have different implementations.

And using `s.mul(2).attr` still doesn't work as it just uses `__finalize__` to propagate all attributes but not really multiply it.

Or maybe I am misunderstanding your question and you just want to propagate but not multiply `attr` as well?

If yes, you can modify your custom `__mul__` function to call `__finalize__`.

```
from pandas import Series


class Xseries(Series):
    _metadata = ['attr']

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return Xseries

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.attr = kwargs.pop('attr', 0)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        internal_result = super().__mul__(other)
        return internal_result.__finalize__(self)

s = Xseries([1, 2, 3], attr=3)
```

If not, you can manually multiply `attr` and return.

```
from pandas import Series


class Xseries(Series):
    _metadata = ['attr']

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return Xseries

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.attr = kwargs.pop('attr', 0)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        internal_result = super().__mul__(other)
        if hasattr(other, "attr"):
            internal_result.attr = self.attr * other.attr
        else:
            internal_result.attr = self.attr * other
        return internal_result

s = Xseries([1, 2, 3], attr=3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are definitely on to something with finalize. To clarify, I do **not** want to multiply attr. Just have it propagated. I'm trying to avoid rewriting methods but will if I have to. I'm leaving the question open to see who else might answer.

Comment: @chrisb thank you.  The work around from [matthiasha](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13208#issuecomment-326556232) solves my problem

Comment: @chrisb if you post a similar answer to one I've posted, I'll delete mine.  If you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

I will delete this answer if @chrisb posts a similar one.

---

As posted by @chrisb [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13208), this is an open issue.

Matthiasha posted a [workaround](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13208#issuecomment-326556232) that is recreated below using my example from the question.

```
from pandas import Series


class Xseries(Series):
    _metadata = ['attr']

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        def _c(*args, **kwargs):
            # workaround for https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13208
            return Xseries(*args, **kwargs).__finalize__(self)
        return _c

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.attr = kwargs.pop('attr', 0)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And now the problem is solved:

```
(Xseries([1, 2, 3], attr=3) * 2).attr

3
```